# Qt does not use system font settings

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I installed musescore (Qt) but it does not seem to use the system font. I tried setting it via QtConfig but that does not work. How can I get system fonts to be used by Qt? I am on Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome.

Comment: Are you using a MuseScore binary or building it in Qt?

Comment: I use this binary:   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install musescore